# Rails i18n nested translations with ActiveRecord backend

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-i18n

I know that I can create nested translations in i18n dictionary.
e.g.

```
en:
  bugs:
    index:
      new_label: "File a new bug"
      edit_label: "edit"
      delete_label: "delete"
```

It works perfect with simple YAML-files. But what will be if I want to use ActiveRecord as backend for i18n?

Smth like this

```
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new
```

I found some migration for this feature

```
class CreateTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :translations do |t|
      t.string :locale
      t.string :key
      t.text   :value
      t.text   :interpolations
      t.boolean :is_proc, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :translations
  end
end
```

How can I save nested translations in this case?
Without it translation must be like

```
{ bugs: value, bugs_index: value, bugs_index_new_label: value, ... }
```

But in my opinion it's not nice solution...

Comment: A yaml is basically a nested hash, a database table is just a plain list. There is not much you can do. What you can try is to use the format Rails uses for scopes, something like: `bugs.index.new_label`, `bugs.index.edit_label`, `bugs.index.delete_label`...

Comment: @spickermann thnx. But I don't understand what scopes you are talking about?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-backends

Comment: @endifix: See 5.1.1 on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models